# AgGrid Component AgLargeTextCellEditor not fully visible in small grid (e. g. 1 row)

Tags: javascript, css, components, ag-grid

I have a question. It is possible to make e.g. AgLargeTextCellEditor overlap the grid if the grid is very small e.g. just 1 line? The problem is that this editor popup is trapped in the grid with just 1 line and does not pop out so that it's not possible to edit the cell like expected. The "popup:true" attribute does not change that. Does anyone know about a tweak?

Thank you very much !

[image]

Comment: Share some code to review and reproduce.

Comment: Just initialize the grid with one or two rows of data and use AgLargeTextCellEditor

Comment: Then add some min-height to your grid.